# PHP Post variable keeps empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I have a main page to display all records of my mysqli database in a table. With a button on each record I can open a detail page to see all of the information. So far so good.
On the detail page the status of a records is displayed as a dropdown menu, and the value of the database set the dropdown item as selected. Now I want that the user can change this dropdown value to another one by changing the dropdown item and with the submit button to update the record and display a message on the same page (This dropdown field and the button is already a form). But the problem is that the $_POST["status"] variable keeps emtpy.

This is the dropdown menu after first page load(view.php) and its also in the connection():

```
if ($res3 = $connection->query($sql3)){
                if ($res3 ->num_rows == 0){
                    echo "No entries";
                    }
                    echo "<tr><td>Ticketstatus</td>";

                    echo "<td><div class='select'><form action='view.php' method='post'><select name='status' >";
                    while($record2= $res3->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo "<option value='" . $record2['id'] . "' "?><?php if($record2['statusname'] == $ticketstatus) echo "selected";?><?php echo ">" . $record2['statusname'] . "</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    echo "<button type='submit' name='update'>save</button>";
                    echo "</form>";
                    echo "</td> </tr></div> ";
                }
```

And this is the page(view.php) beginning(the $_GET["id"] comes from the main page to display the specific record, I need the session to use the record id after page refresh)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset ($_GET["id"])){
    connection($_GET["id"]);
    $_SESSION["id"] = $_GET["id"];
    
}elseif(isset ($_POST["update"])){
        settype($_SESSION["id"], "integer");
        $dbn= "ticketsystem";
        $dbu= "root";
        $dbs= "localhost";
        $ticketid = $_SESSION["id"];
        $connection= @new mysqli($dbs,$dbu,"",$dbn);
        $sqlupdate = "UPDATE ticket SET ticketstatus_fk=? WHERE id=$ticketid";
        $update = $connection->prepare($sqlupdate);
        $update->bind_param("i", $_POST["status"]);
        $update->execute();
        
        $result= $connection->query($sqlupdate) or die($connection->error);
        if($update->affected_rows > 0){
            echo "Saved!";
        }
        $update->close();
        $connection->close();
    
}else{
    echo "Error!";
    exit();
}
```

It shows always a SQL syntax error because the $_POST["status"] is always empty. So what can I try to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use a bound parameter for `$ticketid` as well. This query, as written, is vulnerable to SQL injection. I don't see why `$_POST["status"]` would always be empty, I'd `var_dump($_POST);` to see what you're actually getting.

Comment: Try dumping the contents of `$_POST` using `var_dump($_POST)`;

Comment: I suspect `isset ($_POST["update"])` returns null because the button has no value.  I would try adding a value to the button, e.g. `<button type='submit' name='update' value='submit'>`

Comment: Ok I did a var dump and this is the result: array(2) { ["status"]=> string(0) "" ["update"]=> string(0) "" }